# how to merge 2 pandas dataframes of different sizes/indices on floor(value x, value y)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given 2 pandas dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({col1: [0.5, 0.75, 1.1, 1.6,  2, 3, 5.5, 10, 11.2] })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({col2: [0, 3, 10,15] })
```

Each of the `df1[col1]` value is within the range of `df2[col2]` values:

`df2[col2].iloc[y] <= df1[col1].iloc[x] < df2[col2].iloc[y+1]`

How to merge df1 and df2 in a way that each value from `df1[col1]` equals to the min value of fitting range from `df2[col2]`. E.g. `df1[col1].iloc[1] = 0.75` it resides between `df2[col2].iloc[0]` and `df2[col2].iloc[1]` (0.75 fits the range: 0, 3) so `df1['result'].iloc[1] = df2[col2].iloc[0]`

```
expected result: 

df1['result'] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 10, 10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.Series.values.searchsorted()`, which returns indices where elements should be inserted to maintain order.

for example:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0.5, 0.75, 1.1, 1.6,  2, 3, 5.5, 10, 11.2] })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': [0, 3, 10,15] })

df2['col2'].values.searchsorted(0.5) # return 1
df2['col2'].values.searchsorted(5.5) # return 2
df2['col2'].values.searchsorted(10)  # return 2
```

You want value instead of indices, so like this:

```py
# get indices, return: [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3]
indices = df2['col2'].values.searchsorted(df1['col1'], side='right')

# get values, return: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 10, 10]
df1['result'] = [df2['col2'].iloc[i-1] for i in indices]
```

Comment: @AdR the last 4 values should be `3, 3, 10, 10`, you have `0, 3, 3, 10`

Comment: Sorry for that, I have fixed it to `xxx.searchsorted(df1['col1'], side='right')`. This is problem of left or right index satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom generator to produce the needed sequence:

```
def gen_range_bounds(s1, s2):
    ranges = list(zip(s2[:-1], s2[1:]))  # collect consecutive ranges
    for v in s1:
        for low, high in ranges:
            if low <= v < high:
                yield low  # yield min bound of the range
                break

df1['result'] = list(gen_range_bounds(df1['col1'], df2['col2']))
print(df1)
```

---

```
    col1  result
0   0.50       0
1   0.75       0
2   1.10       0
3   1.60       0
4   2.00       0
5   3.00       3
6   5.50       3
7  10.00      10
8  11.20      10
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some form of inequality join - if that is the case, you can use [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to get your results

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df1
.conditional_join(
    df2.astype(float).assign(col3 = lambda f: f.col2.shift(-1).fillna(f.col2)), 
    ('col1', 'col2', '>='), ('col1', 'col3', '<'), 
    right_columns='col2')
)
    col1  col2
0   0.50   0.0
1   0.75   0.0
2   1.10   0.0
3   1.60   0.0
4   2.00   0.0
5   3.00   3.0
6   5.50   3.0
7  10.00  10.0
8  11.20  10.0
```