# how to merge 2 DataFrames of differenrt sizes on ceil(value x, value y)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have already asked a similar question : [how to merge 2 pandas dataframes of different sizes/indices on floor(value x, value y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75606498/how-to-merge-2-pandas-dataframes-of-different-sizes-indices-on-floorvalue-x-va)

Got answers, which work. I cannot however obtain the upper boundary in the same fashion as suggested in the answers to the previous question, hence publishing another question

Given 2 pandas dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({col1: [0.5, 0.75, 1.1, 1.6,  2, 3, 5.5, 10, 11.2] })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({col2: [0, 3, 10,15] })
```

Each of the `df1[col1]` value is within the range of `df2[col2]` values:

`df2[col2].iloc[y] <= df1[col1].iloc[x] < df2[col2].iloc[y+1]`

How to merge df1 and df2 in a way that each value from `df1[col1]` equals to the max value of fitting range from `df2[col2]`. E.g. `df1[col1].iloc[1] = 0.75` it resides between `df2[col2].iloc[0]` and `df2[col2].iloc[1]` (0.75 fits the range: 0, 3) so `df1['result'].iloc[1] = df2[col2].iloc[1]`

```
expected result: 

df1['result'] = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 10, 10, 15, 15]
```

Comment: In luhao's answer to the previous question in the second code snippet replace the `iloc[i-1]` by `iloc[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.cut`:

```
eps = 1e-6  # to include the left part

df1['result'] = pd.cut(df1['col1'], bins=df2['col2']-eps, 
                       labels=df2['col2'].iloc[1:])
print(df1)

# Output
    col1 result
0   0.50      3
1   0.75      3
2   1.10      3
3   1.60      3
4   2.00      3
5   3.00     10
6   5.50     10
7  10.00     15
8  11.20     15
```

With `np.searchsorted`, use `side='right'`

```
df1['result'] = df2.loc[np.searchsorted(df2['col2'], df1['col1'], side='right')].values
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some form of inequality join - if that is the case, you can use [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to get your results

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df1
.conditional_join(
    df2.astype(float).assign(col3 = lambda f: f.col2.shift(-1).fillna(f.col2)), 
    ('col1', 'col2', '>='), 
    ('col1', 'col3', '<'), 
    right_columns={'col3':'col2'})
)
    col1  col2
0   0.50   3.0
1   0.75   3.0
2   1.10   3.0
3   1.60   3.0
4   2.00   3.0
5   3.00  10.0
6   5.50  10.0
7  10.00  15.0
8  11.20  15.0
```